# Do I need to develop on Vista to write to the wmdc (windows mobile device center) API?

Tags: windows-vista, activesync, wmdc

Can I write and compile code for this on XP?  We have utilities for our apps that use activesync and now will be adding Vista/WMDC - and I was hoping I don't have to have another development OS (Vista) to develop and compile on.

I have not seen much documentation for the API for WMDC - can someone point me to some useful references for it?

Answer (score 1):

hummm... ActiveSync, so Windows Mobile am I right?

all you need is the SDK and Visual Studio (well, this last you don't need cause you can compile everything using the command line, but, very nice to have for such applications)

there are plenty of SDKs for what you need, for example [PocketPC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=83A52AF2-F524-4EC5-9155-717CBE5D25ED&displaylang=en), [Windows Mobile](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en), etc...

the sdk contains everything you need to build, compile and deploy an application, works fine on windows XP (what I currently use) and with ActiveSync, you can even debug the application in the device ;)

added:

> unfortunatelly there is no SDK for the WMDC. The only thing you have are the 4 libraries in the %WinDir%\Windows Mobile. It contains 4 libraries named as "Microsoft.WindowsMobile.*.dll". Additionally you don't get any documentation on the libraries themselves which makes it hard to use.
>
> As you use the RAPI (I think by using the OpenNETCF library) most of the applications shall still run under WMDC as the included RAPI seems to be backward compatible. The included RAPI itself is in a new version.

```
taken from MSDN forum
```

I hope this helps for the moment.

Comment: I think perhaps I was not clear - I need to programmatically access activesync and (on Vista) WMDC - so that my applications can do syncing with the mobile application we have installed on the device.  (the analogy is syncing with mail from Outlook)

Comment: I see you added content.  thanks that clarifies why I have not seen much useful information - especially from MS...  thanks for the help